# Replace all String with empty string starting with --

Tags: javascript

i have string which is

```
testVariable--423h33c7uhyga5tjk
```

now i want to replace the above string with

```
testVariable
```

by using `javascript` replace function.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```js
console.log(
  'testVariable--423h33c7uhyga5tjk'.replace('--')[0]
)
```

---

Or with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
console.log(
  'testVariable--423h33c7uhyga5tjk'.replace(/--.*/, '')
  // or including multiline
  // .replace(/--[\s\S]*/, '')
)
```

Comment: i want to use the javascript replace function with regex.

Comment: @MansoorAkhtar :  check updTE

Comment: thanks that worked.

Answer (score 0):

While Pranav's method work, if you really need/Want to use the replace function, you could use regex:

```
var variable = 'testVariable--423h33c7uhyga5tjk';
console.log(variable.replace(/--.+$/, ''));
```